# How to use std::unique to remove unique character in vector (c++)

Tags: c++, stl

I need to remove unique characters in a vector
`v.erase(unique(v.begin(),v.end()));`
what is problem with this.
input:wxwwm
output:wxm

```
 `vector<string>v;    
  string s;   
  cin >>s;   
  v.push_back(s);   
  v.erase(unique(v.begin(),v.end()),v.end());     
  for(auto i=v.begin();i!=v.end();i++)    
  {  
   cout <<*i;  
   }`
```

Comment: `std::unique` removes *adjacent, duplicate* values. That's not at all the same as *values that appear once*

Comment: **You** are supposed to say what the problem with this code is. You are supposed to show a [mcve], say what the code did and what you expected instead. There is no good way for us to guess what you wanted.

Comment: What does `v` contain at the start, and what do you want it to end up with?

Comment: There are various problems.   Either you want to remove duplicates, or you want to remove any values that have no duplicates.   Your code does neither - if there is more than one duplicate, only one duplicate is removed by your code.

Comment: Please show some examples of input and output. Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @Caleth check now

Comment: The example code puts one string read from `cin` into a vector, then prints that string to `cout`. Did you mean to remove the duplicate characters from the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::unique` doesn't do what you require here. You will have to do something else.

From [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) (emphasis mine)

> Eliminates all but the first element from every **consecutive group** of equivalent elements

A simple way to test if you have seen an element previously is to add it to a set.

```
std::string s = "wxwwm";
std::set<char> seen;
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [&seen](char c){ return !seen.insert(c).second; }), s.end());
std::cout << s; // outputs wxm
```

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: This answer was applicable to the previous, slightly unclear version of the question. For the answer to the current question, see **[Caleth's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53617256/7151494)** answer.

---

`std::unique` removes the adjacent duplicates (actually pushes them to the end of the given range, to make them very suitable for later removal with `erase`). That's not what you want.

If you want to remove **unique** elements, then I would propose a solution based on counting the distinct elements' occurrences and them removing those which occur only once. Take a look at this function:

```
template <typename T>
void remove_unique(std::vector<T>& vec) {
    std::map<T, int> occurrences {};

    for(const auto& element : vec) {
        occurrences[element]++;
    }

    const auto to_remove = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
            [&occurrences](const auto& element) {
                return occurrences[element] == 1;
            }
    );

    vec.erase(to_remove, vec.end());
}
```

This will remove all unique elements from a `std::vector` containing any type (given it's copyable).

It uses a `std::map` to count the occurrences of every element in a vector and then uses `std::remove_if`, which will (similarily to `std::unique`) push elements that satisfy a certain criteria to the end of the range, to make them sutiable for actual removal. The *certain criteria* in this example is the satisfaction of a predicate - a lambda, which checks if the given element occurred only once (this information is provided by our map, which we capture in the lambda). Afterwards, we simply remove those elements with `erase` call.

Usage:

```
int main() {
    // two 2s and two 3s
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 2, 9, 3};

    remove_unique(vec);

    for(const auto i : vec) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output of this program is: `2 3 2 3`. All unique elements have been removed